# getting a 404 error when trying to navigate to signin route in heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, mern

I have deployed my mern app to heroku, but it shows me a 404 page error when I try to navigate to the routes by entering the url. The navbar links work fine and they successfully navigate me to the signin and sign up pages, but when I click the register, login links in the forms. those links are broken and it gives me a Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) instead.
you can check my app at https://fullstack-restaurant-app97.herokuapp.com/
Im getting the error when Im navigating to https://fullstack-restaurant-app97.herokuapp.com/signin or https://fullstack-restaurant-app97.herokuapp.com/signup routes.

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "cd frontend && npm run build",
    "install-frontend": "cd frontend && npm install",
    "start": "node ./src/server.js",
    "server": "nodemon ./src/server.js",
    "frontend": "cd frontend && npm start",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false && npm run install-frontend && npm run build"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-validator": "^6.6.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "shortid": "^2.2.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

App.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Signin from './containers/Signin';
import Signup from './containers/Signup';
import Home from './containers/Home';
import './App.css';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { isUserLoggedIn } from './actions';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';


function App() {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const auth = useSelector(state => state.auth)

  useEffect(() => {
    if(!auth.authenticate){
      dispatch(isUserLoggedIn())
    }
    
  }, [])
  return (
    <>
    <CssBaseline/>
    <Router>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/signin" component={Signin} />
      <Route path="/signup" component={Signup}/>    
    </Router>
    </>
      );
}

export default App;
```

server.js

```
const express= require('express');
const app= express();
const mongoose= require('mongoose');
const env= require('dotenv').config();
const PORT= process.env.PORT || 2000;
const adminRoutes= require('./routes/admin/auth');
const restaurantRoutes= require('./routes/restaurant')
const cors= require('cors');
const path= require('path');

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || `mongodb+srv://${process.env.MONGO_DB_USER}:${process.env.MONGO_DB_PASSWORD}@cluster0.e4r3t.mongodb.net/${process.env.MONGO_DB_DATABASE}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`, 
{
    useNewUrlParser: true, 
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex:true
}).then(() => {
    console.log('Database connected');
});

app.use(cors());
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname,'uploads')));
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/api', adminRoutes);
app.use('/api', restaurantRoutes);


if(process.env.NODE_ENV=='production'){
    app.use(express.static("frontend/build"))
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend', 'build', 'index.html'))
    })

    
}



app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
})
```

I have also added the link to my github repo https://github.com/codinghamster12/fullstack-restaurant-webapp
I have tried to fix this for days now and I would really appreciate if someone could look into it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot directly say this is the reason for happening that. But you can use a simple method to find out the problem. Navigate to the project folder and open cmd from that location. Then, login to your heroku account by using `heroku login` command. Then type `heroku logs -t` command it will show up the status of your server and API calls init. If there any error you can see the error message in red color. Then go through it you can definitely come up with a solution by using this method.

Comment: I tried that and I fixed the error, it was because my build folder was in the .gitgnore file. thank you for your help!

Comment: Ok, great to hear that.